# Any way to debug RSpec request specs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am writing a test for a Rails API in RSpec and the endpoint has token authentication set up. I need to pass an Authorization header in the request, but I keep getting a 401 unauthorized error. Is there any way to debug and get some insight into actually which headers are being passed etc. from these types of specs? Otherwise it seems like shooting in the dark. I should note that the token provided below is working perfectly in Postman.

```
describe "Chirps API" do
    it "GET /chirps should return 200" do
        get "/chirps", headers: {
            "Authorization": "Token token=7cc9f851ea0e4013b7b15ec9131f6d58"
        }

        expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    end
end
```

Comment: Rubymine has a really good IDE debugger that works well for this type of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your controller action is chirps as well, this will help you see the complete request object

```
def chirps
  Rails.logger.info(request.env) # complete request object
  Rails.logger.info(request.headers) #just the headers
 ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

To be more interactive you can insert a byebug, then issue the command.

```
it { byebug }
```

Then enter your **get** in the console.